# Pepper ignores IF ELSE completely

Tags: python, pepper

I'm analysing an AWS response in python in the following script:

```
#var definition
conversationName = 'NO NAME'

#in the MyClass
    if len(resp['FaceMatches'])>0:
        faceRecognized = resp['FaceMatches'][0]['Face']['ExternalImageId']
        self.logger.info(str(faceRecognized))

        if resp['FaceMatches'][0]['Face']['ExternalImageId'] == self.conversationName:
            self.logger.info("Name is the same")
            return
        else:
            self.logger.info('Name has changed!')
            self.conversationName=faceRecognized.split('_')[0]
            self.pepperTTS.say("Hi "+str(faceRecognized.split('_')[0])+". Can I help you with something?")
            return
    else:
        self.logger.info("No face rekognized so far.")
        return
```

Problem is with the second IF ELSE. When I run the programm it seems to ignore this IF ELSE completely and neither prints "Name is the same" nor "Name has changed". And it does not show any errors when running the script.

Does anyone see the error or can give some tips to correct the script?

Comment: Does the script print "No face rekognized so far."?  If `if len(resp['FaceMatches']) > 0` evaluates as `false` then your inner `if-else` would not be evaluated and you would not print either of the values you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What's most likely happening is that `resp['FaceMatches'][0]['Face']['ExternalImageId']` is raising an exception because one of those keys / indexes is wrong, and then the exception is not getting caught and gets swallowed silently - it's unfortunate, but in NAOqi a lot of exceptions get swallowed if no-one catches them (for example, in the callback in an ALMemory subscribe - as you probably have here).

So you should wrap all that chunk in a big try/except and print whatever exception gets caught.

This is a common enough situation that I created a helper library ([documented here](https://github.com/pepperhacking/studiotoolkit/blob/master/doc/stk_logging.md)) with a log_exceptions decorators you can put on any function that swallows exceptions (typically: ALMemory event and signal callbacks; anything called with qi.async, anything called from outside your service ...), so your code doesn't get cluttered with try/except all over the place.